# Update list Aspnet core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to update a list of items most do not know how to do, when my only method adciona new items to existing inves change.

save change

```
public async Task<CommandResult> ExecuteAsync(EventsCommandsHandler handler)
        {
            var listItens = await handler.DbContext.ListItens
                .Where(f => f.Id == this.Id)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            listItens.SetData(
                name: Name,
                description: Description
            );

            handler.DbContext.ListItens.Update(listItens);

            if (Items.Length > 0)
            {
                var itens = Items
                    .Select(p => p.ToItemList(listItens.Id))
                    .Where(p => p != null)
                    .ToArray();
                await handler.DbContext.ItemsList.(itens);
            }

            var rows = await handler.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

            return await Task.FromResult(new CommandResult(rows));
        }


create intens


  public static ItemList ToItemList(this ItemCommand command, string listId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.Description))
                return null;

            var itens = new ItemList(
                id: String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(command.Id) ? RandomId.NewId(8) : command.Id,
                description: command.Description,
                listId: listId
            );
            return itens;
        }
```

I need a way for this method.
I have a list and this list has items, when I edit the list, I want to be able to delete, edit or add more items.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "I need a way for this method"?

Answer (score 0):

You have a To-Do list. There should be an add button.

A post request should be sent and data should be written to the database, and page - updated when you press any button like remove, edit and add.

If you want it to be async, then you should use JavaScript or Blazor.